# How to hook when all the subscribers of a `Subject` are unsubscribed?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to extend Subject for the below given cases

1. accept a function that gives me an invokeable http request (For now an observable from angular HttpClient)
2. When the first subscriber subscribes invoke the http request
3. When the request succeeds invoke the `next()` so all the subscribers are notified.
4. Support a new method `reload()` that can reinvoke the http request when called.
5. reload method should trigger the http request only if there are open subscribers.
6. When a new subscriber subscribes and a response is already available existing response should be passed (Like BehaviourSubject)
7. **If reload method was triggered and then the last active subscriber was unsubscribed the http request should be cancelled**

This is what I have tried and have achieved 6 of 7 things mentioned. I'm trying to accomplish the 7th item also.
If I had a hook for all the unsubscribe() calls I'd simply call the http unsubscribe when there are no subscribers.

extended Subject class and declared a constructor (1)

```js
    constructor(dataFetcher : () => Observable<T>) {
        super();
        this.dataFetcher = dataFetcher;
    }
```

I made override method for _subscribe so if a known data is available it will be sent to any new subscription (6) and also if it is the first subscription I'll trigger the http request using fetchData() (2)

```js
    _subscribe(subscriber : Subscriber<T>) : Subscription {
        const subscription = super._subscribe(subscriber);
        if(subscription && !subscription.closed && this.lastKnownData){
            subscriber.next(this.lastKnownData);
        }
        if(this.isFirstSubscription){
            this.isFirstSubscription = false;
            this.fetchData();
        }
        return subscription;
    }
```

I added a method reload() to invoke the http request again when called (4) and made sure the request is not triggered when there are no subscribers (5)

```js
    public reload() : void {
        if(this.observers && this.observers.length > 0){
            for (let i = 0; i < this.observers.length; i++) {
                if(!this.observers[i].closed){
                    this.fetchData();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally fetchData that would trigger the request by subscribing and unsubscribing the dataFetcher received in the constructor (3)

```js
    private fetchData() : void {
        this.dataFetcherSubscription = this.dataFetcher().subscribe(this.dataFetcherSubscriptionCallback.bind(this));
    }

    private dataFetcherSubscriptionCallback(data : T) : void{
        this.lastKnownData = data;
        this.next(data);
        if(this.dataFetcherSubscription){
            this.dataFetcherSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a subject problem here. You're mixing together different things that should not be mixed together. `reload()` should be an observable and not a function, and the concept of "subscribers" is a **state** for a *shared service*. You're trying to merge together different things into a new subject. I don't think it's a wise thing to do.

Comment: As I see, advantage of using an observable over a promise is that it keeps emitting events on every data change. Based on this I made different Subjects for each entity. To make this work I made a service full of subjects, in a component init bind with required subjects. when user performs any action, update the subject's value. which would update all the components that are observing that particular subject.
By this I made sure there is only one source of truth which is the service with subjects.

Comment: If I had to spawn an observable for each reload just to get a new value, Its purpose would be just similar to a promise, I thought. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong. or if there is a better or recommended way to go about this. 
@Reactgular

Comment: That does sound a lot better. You can update the question so show what you've tried now.

Comment: Just to achieve what I said in the previous comment I've made an extension for Subject as RequestSubject. 
1) Why Subject override? for accepting a function that get's me an http observable `this.http.get(***)` and support for reload() method....
2) Why reload ? Say I have an updateEmployeeDetails component and EmployeeComponent after update in updateEmployeeDetails i'd just have to call reload method of employee subject and It'll make the API call for me.....
3) Why function ? For reload method I'd want to repeat the API call, so to create a new `this.http.get()` observable @Reactgular :)